# Regex + Python - Remove all lines beginning with a *

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove all lines from a given file that begin with a *. So for example, the following:

```
* This needs to be gone
But this line should stay
*remove 
* this too
End
```

Should generate this:

```
But this line should stay
End
```

---

What I ultimately need to do is the following:

1. Remove all text inside parenthesis and brackets (parenthesis/brackets included),
2. As mentioned above, remove lines starting with ''.

So far I was able to address #1 with the following: `re.sub(r'[.?]|(.*?)', '', fileString)`. I tried several things for #2 but always end up removing things I don't want to

---

**Solution 1 (no regex)**

```
>>> f = open('path/to/file.txt', 'r')
>>> [n for n in f.readlines() if not n.startswith('*')]
```

**Solution 2 (regex)**

```
>>> s = re.sub(r'(?m)^\*.*\n?', '', s)
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: so what have you come up with so far?

Comment: What I ultimately need to do is the following:
1 - Remove all text inside parenthesis and brackets (parenthesis/brackets included), 2 - As mentioned above, remove lines starting with \*. So far I was able to address #1 with the following: re.sub(r'\[.*?\]|\(.*?\)', '', fileString). I tried several things for #2 but always end up removing things I don't want to.

Comment: I've moved that into your question so it's easier to read. For simple stuff, you can avoid using a regex, and use builtin str methods, something like: `if not line.lstrip().startswith('*')`

Comment: @JonClements Thanks! (for the edit and suggestion). I'll try that.

And I'm not sure what the reason for the down vote is. I'd understand if I were asking for homework solution, hadn't tried anything myself, or hadn't done any research before. In any case I appreciate everybody's time :)

Answer (score 6):

Using regex >>

```
s = re.sub(r'(?m)^\*.*\n?', '', s)
```

Check **[this demo](http://ideone.com/mCq4i)**.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for this.

```
text = file.split('\n') # split everything into lines.

for line in text:
    # do something here
```

Let us know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 1):

You should really give more information here.  At the minimum, what version of python you are using and a code snippet.  But, that said, why do you need a regular expression?  I don't see why you can't just use startswith.

The following works for me with Python 2.7.3

```
s = '* this line gotta go!!!'
print s.startswith('*')

>>>True
```

Comment: 2.7.3, which I just started using yesterday, hence my total clueless. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give that a try.

Comment: @EveraldoAguiar welcome to StackOverflow!  And no problem - I have had the same suggestion made about my questions on multiple occasions.  In general, it's good to try and ask as specific of a question as possible.  And to post a code snippet of what you've tried.  If you are getting an error, include that.  And with Python, it's usually a good idea to include the version you are using (because there are significant difference between 3.x and older versions).  But, just keep asking questions.  I think you will find the community very willing to try and help.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> f = open('path/to/file.txt', 'r')
>>> [n for n in f.readlines() if not n.startswith('*')]
['But this line should stay\n', 'End\n']
```