# How do I delete line starting with ">" while reading a file to string in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to read all files ending with ".fasta" in mydir directory one by one and save content except lines starting with ">" to a string called "data" for further analysis while also ignoring newline characters. So far I have this:

```
for file in os.listdir(mydir):
  if file.endswith(".fasta"):
    with open(file, 'r') as myfile:
      data = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
```

How do I read file into a string AND in the same command skip all lines starting with ">"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex + Python - Remove all lines beginning with a \*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925191/regex-python-remove-all-lines-beginning-with-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
for file in os.listdir(mydir):
  if file.endswith(".fasta"):
    with open(file, 'r') as myfile:
      data = "".join(line for line in myfile if line[:1]!='>')
```

Comment: @PyreneanIbex: you don't need to use the slice `line[:1]!='>'`. Use index  access `line[0] != '>'` or `not line.startswith('>')` instead.

Comment: @YoavGlazner I don't think that `for line in file` may produce an empty line (`len(line)>0`). Could you provide a counter-example (file content as a bytes literal e.g., `b'\n'` does not yield empty line)?

Comment: As I said explicitly, `b'\n'` does NOT produce empty line. `\n\n\n\n\n` produces `['\n']*5` (NO empty lines)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - You are right! I don't have counter example :)